# Devise - No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out: Any alternatives to requiring jquery-ujs, setting config.sign_out_via = :get, or using button_to?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using Devise for a large app with multiple engines and am looking for an alternative solution to the three options given below to destroy an user's session path:

1. require jquery-ujs
2. change config.sign_out_via = :delete to config.sign_out_via = :get
3. use button_to instead of link_to

I'm currently require jquery-ujs and am able to successfully log out, but would prefer not to have to use this dependency for my solution.

= link_to 'Log Out', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete

I will settle for require jquery-ujs if necessary, but am hoping someone out there knows another solution.  Thanks!

Comment: you have all solutions here, if you dont accept any... I dont know what to say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an additional route to your app to point to the standard devise log out action.

```
devise_scope :user do
  get '/users/sign_out', to: 'devise/sessions#destroy'
end
```

Then you'll have log out via both `DELETE` and `GET`